# CakePHP saveField NULL value in a INT column

Tags: cakephp

I want to update one column which is an INT with a NULL value. I'm using CakePHP 2.3 with the saveField('field', 'value') method.

Here is my code :

```
$this->Customer->id = $customer_id;
if ($this->Customer->saveField('account_id', 'NULL')) {
     //Do some stuff
}
```

So when I put 'NULL', the row is updated to 0. I tried NULL without quotes and the row is not updated.

EDIT :
The field in the db accepts NULL value.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: obvious question, but anyway: is your db field configured so that it can be null?

Comment: Yes it is with default value set to NULL. I update the post

Comment: Take a read on this link: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Jippi/2007/03/25/null-behavior    seems like this is an issue many people experience?

Comment: @TheCapn Your link is more than 5 years old. CakePHP has changed a bit since.

Comment: Post the query it's generating that attempts to insert the null value

Comment: @kdelemme - if you're not already using DebugKit (https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit), stop everything now, and go install it (not joking).  It will show you every query that's run, all variables that are on a page, and lots and lots of other handy things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not pass `'NULL'` as a string but as `null` value:

```
if($this->Customer->saveField('account_id', null))
{
  //do some stuff
}
else
{
  //do you get anything here ?
  debug($this->Customer->validationErrors);
}
```

Comment: I already tried that like I said in the post. This doesn't update the row.

Comment: Actually, the //do some stuff is executed.

Comment: It is also executed with the `null` value ?

Comment: Yes with 'NULL', NULL and null. Only the 'NULL' value update my row to 0. the others do nothing.

Comment: It is strange if that does nothing but returns true. Do you have any callback in your Customer model, such as `beforeSave()` ? Try to set the debug level to 2 and check the SQL query that is generated.

Comment: Ok I found my issue. In my beforeSave in AppModel.php I unset all value equal to '', to let MySQL uses default value when inserting/updating. Why saveField('key', NULL) is like $key == '' ?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similiar problem caused by a Upload Behaviour that had validations preventing the saving. Check your models, it might help. I assume saveField returns true even when validation rules prevent saving.